# PL/SQL JOIN使用時にCURSOR で更新できない

Tags: oracle, plsql

PL/SQLでCURSORを使用してUPDATEしようとしているのですが、
正常終了するものの、更新がされていません。何が問題でしょうか?

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( 
    COL1    CHAR(3),
    COL2    CHAR(3)
);
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 ( 
    COL1    CHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('ABC','001');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES('ABC');
COMMIT;
```

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR C1_CURSOR IS

      SELECT T1.COL1,T1.COL2
        FROM TABLE1 T1
        JOIN TABLE2 T2
          ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1
      FOR UPDATE;
             
   C1 C1_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
   OPEN C1_CURSOR;
   LOOP
      FETCH C1_CURSOR INTO C1;
      EXIT WHEN C1_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
 
      UPDATE TABLE1
         SET COL2 = '999'
        WHERE CURRENT OF C1_CURSOR;

  END LOOP;
   CLOSE C1_CURSOR;

   COMMIT;

END;
```

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
```

**⇒ COL2 が '999'になっていない!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご質問のように複数のテーブルを等価結合する時は、更新するテーブルに対して明示的にロックを掛けないとレコードが特定できないようです。
つまり`FOR UPDATE;`を`FOR UPDATE OF T1.COL2;`に書き換えるとうまく行きます。
cf: [SELECT 時に明示的な行ロックを行なう方法](https://www.shift-the-oracle.com/sql/select-for-update.html)

また、単純にROWIDで一意に特定する代替手段もあります。
カーソルのselect句に`T1.ROWID`を追加し、update文のwhere句を`WHERE ROWID = C1.ROWID;`に書き換える方法です。
cf: [CURRENT OFの疑似実行について](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57425_01/121/LNPCC/GUID-DBA71301-C6C4-47C0-BAB5-1B6B221AB46E.htm)

もしくは単一テーブルに対するカーソルであれば一意の行が特定できるので、EXISTS句に書き換えることで`FOR UPDATE`でも対応可能です。

```
CURSOR C1_CURSOR IS
  SELECT T1.COL1,T1.COL2
    FROM TABLE1 T1
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.COL1 = T2.COL1)
  FOR UPDATE;
```

本家SOの類似質問？: [Oracle FOR UPDATE (OF) Cursor behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35722867)

Comment: 明示的にロックを掛ける事で解決しました。大変助かりました。
エラーにならないからと言って更新されていない事もあるのですね。